# HTML E-Mail with IMAGE and PDF

Tags: html, image, email, pdf, attachment

I want to create

- HTML e-mail
- with 1 image
- and 1 pdf

and send it via MS Outlook

Here is my approach:

I created a table with 1 row:

- Column 1: should display the image
- Column 2: should display the pdf-icon (file opens if user clicks the icon)

**What did I do so far?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>E-Mail</title>
</head>

<body > 
<table border=1 >
 <tr>
  <td>   
   <img src="images/report.png" alt="report image, replace with your image" />
  </td>
   
  <td >
   PDF will be attached later once this HTML file is attached via "Insert as Text".
   So finally "PDF icon" should appear here. Once user clicks, pdf application opens the content.
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

**... then**

1. In Outlook I attach the HTML file above via "Insert Text".
2. I changed the "Format Text" to "Rich Text"
3. I attached the pdf file via drag & drop in the 2nd column

**Problem**

Other user receives the email, BUT

- image from "column 1" disappears completely from the email
- pdf attachment from "column 2" is in the mail, but not in the "column 2"

How can I fix this issue?

Many Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, you can't reliably link to an attachment in the e-mail.  You would have to link to an HTTP server.  Probably best to leave the attachment icons and UI up to the e-mail client anyway.

Comment: Why don't use PHPmailer?